# how to make table with freezed columns in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-table

Flutter table

how to make table with freezed columns with headers and footer in flutter

like this [table example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11KooNy2FRqB0_c6KykrzhAQ9keIn7MQh/view)

I want the height of table to be dynamic depends on the table rows
and i want to put another table under this table

Comment: what do you mean by freezed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/horizontal_data_table

code snippet

```
HorizontalDataTable(
        leftHandSideColumnWidth: 100,
        rightHandSideColumnWidth: 600,
        isFixedHeader: true,
        headerWidgets: _getTitleWidget(),
        leftSideItemBuilder: _generateFirstColumnRow,
        rightSideItemBuilder: _generateRightHandSideColumnRow,
        itemCount: user.userInfo.length,
        rowSeparatorWidget: const Divider(
          color: Colors.black54,
          height: 1.0,
          thickness: 0.0,
        ),
        leftHandSideColBackgroundColor: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
        rightHandSideColBackgroundColor: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
      )
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:horizontal_data_table/horizontal_data_table.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  static const int sortName = 0;
  static const int sortStatus = 1;
  bool isAscending = true;
  int sortType = sortName;

  @override
  void initState() {
    user.initData(100);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _getBodyWidget(),
    );
  }

  Widget _getBodyWidget() {
    return Container(
      child: HorizontalDataTable(
        leftHandSideColumnWidth: 100,
        rightHandSideColumnWidth: 600,
        isFixedHeader: true,
        headerWidgets: _getTitleWidget(),
        leftSideItemBuilder: _generateFirstColumnRow,
        rightSideItemBuilder: _generateRightHandSideColumnRow,
        itemCount: user.userInfo.length,
        rowSeparatorWidget: const Divider(
          color: Colors.black54,
          height: 1.0,
          thickness: 0.0,
        ),
        leftHandSideColBackgroundColor: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
        rightHandSideColBackgroundColor: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
      ),
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _getTitleWidget() {
    return [
      FlatButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        child: _getTitleItemWidget(
            'Name' + (sortType == sortName ? (isAscending ? '↓' : '↑') : ''),
            100),
        onPressed: () {
          sortType = sortName;
          isAscending = !isAscending;
          user.sortName(isAscending);
          setState(() {});
        },
      ),
      FlatButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        child: _getTitleItemWidget(
            'Status' +
                (sortType == sortStatus ? (isAscending ? '↓' : '↑') : ''),
            100),
        onPressed: () {
          sortType = sortStatus;
          isAscending = !isAscending;
          user.sortStatus(isAscending);
          setState(() {});
        },
      ),
      _getTitleItemWidget('Phone', 200),
      _getTitleItemWidget('Register', 100),
      _getTitleItemWidget('Termination', 200),
    ];
  }

  Widget _getTitleItemWidget(String label, double width) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(label, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      width: width,
      height: 56,
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 0, 0),
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
    );
  }

  Widget _generateFirstColumnRow(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(user.userInfo[index].name),
      width: 100,
      height: 52,
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 0, 0),
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
    );
  }

  Widget _generateRightHandSideColumnRow(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(
                  user.userInfo[index].status
                      ? Icons.notifications_off
                      : Icons.notifications_active,
                  color:
                      user.userInfo[index].status ? Colors.red : Colors.green),
              Text(user.userInfo[index].status ? 'Disabled' : 'Active')
            ],
          ),
          width: 100,
          height: 52,
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 0, 0),
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        ),
        Container(
          child: Text(user.userInfo[index].phone),
          width: 200,
          height: 52,
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 0, 0),
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        ),
        Container(
          child: Text(user.userInfo[index].registerDate),
          width: 100,
          height: 52,
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 0, 0),
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        ),
        Container(
          child: Text(user.userInfo[index].terminationDate),
          width: 200,
          height: 52,
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 0, 0),
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

User user = User();

class User {
  List<UserInfo> _userInfo = List<UserInfo>();

  void initData(int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      _userInfo.add(UserInfo(
          "User_$i", i % 3 == 0, '+001 9999 9999', '2019-01-01', 'N/A'));
    }
  }

  List<UserInfo> get userInfo => _userInfo;

  set userInfo(List<UserInfo> value) {
    _userInfo = value;
  }

  ///
  /// Single sort, sort Name's id
  void sortName(bool isAscending) {
    _userInfo.sort((a, b) {
      int aId = int.tryParse(a.name.replaceFirst('User_', ''));
      int bId = int.tryParse(b.name.replaceFirst('User_', ''));
      return (aId - bId) * (isAscending ? 1 : -1);
    });
  }

  ///
  /// sort with Status and Name as the 2nd Sort
  void sortStatus(bool isAscending) {
    _userInfo.sort((a, b) {
      if (a.status == b.status) {
        int aId = int.tryParse(a.name.replaceFirst('User_', ''));
        int bId = int.tryParse(b.name.replaceFirst('User_', ''));
        return (aId - bId);
      } else if (a.status) {
        return isAscending ? 1 : -1;
      } else {
        return isAscending ? -1 : 1;
      }
    });
  }
}

class UserInfo {
  String name;
  bool status;
  String phone;
  String registerDate;
  String terminationDate;

  UserInfo(this.name, this.status, this.phone, this.registerDate,
      this.terminationDate);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @chunhunghan for your code it works fine.

I want to but this code in SingleChildScrollView because i want to make two tables under each other and i want the height of the table to be dynamic

Comment: and how to add footer to table